# The best way of flushing data buffers in DirectFB

Tags: c, linux

I am working with a Set-Top-Box MMI (Multi Media Interface) based on Opera Browser. Opera sends continuously data buffers to be flushed on the screen. I have two solutions implementing this feature.

1. The first one uses only a double buffered primary surface (named 'surface'). Opera writes directly on it.
2. The second solution has two surfaces: an offscreen surface 'bsurface' and a primary double buffered surface 'surface'.

I want to know which one offers more performance and stability for the STB device ? and why ? You should know that my STB hardware is based on Intel Chipset. All your opinions are welcome.

```
/*******************************************************************************
1) flush_buffer: flush callback
*******************************************************************************/
static void flush_buffer(GogiRect *rects, int num_rects, GogiScreenHandle screen)
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < num_rects; ++i)
   {
      DFBRegion update_region = {rects[i].x,
                                 rects[i].y,
                                 rects[i].x+rects[i].w,
                                 rects[i].y+rects[i].h};

      DFBCHECK(surface->Flip(surface, &update_region, DSBLIT_NOFX));
   }

}

/*******************************************************************************
2) flush_buffer: flush callback
*******************************************************************************/.
static void flush_buffer(GogiRect *rects, int num_rects, GogiScreenHandle screen)
{
   int i;
   DFBRegion update_region = {op_width, op_height, 0, 0};
   DFBCHECK(surface->SetBlittingFlags(surface, DSBLIT_NOFX));
   for (i = 0; i < num_rects; ++i)
   {
      DFBRectangle rect = {rects[i].x,
                           rects[i].y,
                           rects[i].w,
                           rects[i].h};

      DFBCHECK(surface->Blit( surface, bsurface, &rect, rect.x, rect.y ));

      if (rects[i].x < update_region.x1) {
         update_region.x1 = rects[i].x;
      }
      if (rects[i].y < update_region.y1) {
         update_region.y1 = rects[i].y;
      }
      if (rects[i].x+rects[i].w > update_region.x2) {
         update_region.x2 = rects[i].x+rects[i].w;
      }
      if (rects[i].y+rects[i].h > update_region.y2) {
         update_region.y2 = rects[i].y+rects[i].h;
      }
   }
   DFBCHECK(surface->Flip(surface, &update_region, DSFLIP_BLIT));

}
```

Comment: It is really difficoult to spot performance issues just looking at the code (several factors can affect the actual runtime performances) Have you tried benchmarking both solutions?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "display issue"? screen flickering or just overall feeling that the system is slower? As you have both implementation, by benchmarking I meant: have you tried understanding how "fast" the two pieces of code runs?

Comment: No i did'nt try benshmarking . I mean by performance the display quality and graphics rendering. In fact, i have a problem when using the first solution : we get a "flicking" menu display while subtitle are displayed character by character.

Comment: So in reality there are two running  processes: Opera process  which displays the menu (by creating its own direcffb instance). And on the other hand we have the subtitle thread wich have also its directfb object and interfaces.  The posted source code is for opera process.

Comment: @sergico I presume by "benchmarking" you mean "profiling", right?

Comment: I guess. what I meant was measuring the performance of both pieces of code (so I guess profiling is also a suitable term)